# jqT page transition issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

I am trying to use jqtouch for page transitions in a web app. The problem is that I do not know how to initiate the pagechange.

In jQuery Mobile I was doing page changes as such:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#landingPage", {
            transition: "cube",
            reverse: true,
            changeHash: false
        });
```

what would be the exact equivalent of the above code but in jQTouch?

This is how I established the jQT variable:

```
var jQT = new $.jQT({    // `new` keyword is now mandatory (was optional before rc6)

            addGlossToIcon: false,
            cubeSelector: '.cubeClass',
            startupScreen: 'Site_Images/startUp1136.PNG',
            statusBar: 'black-translucent',
            preloadImages: []

        });
```

Comment: jqt cane be found here: http://www.jqtjs.com/